# Column and row space of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Are the row space and the column space of a symmetric matrix identical? And what is the relationship to a matrix of eigenvectors and the transpose of the eigenvectors?
Thanks.

Comment: they are isomorphic under the transpose mapping. Identical? Well, if you mean isomorphic by identical then ok... but, technically, a row and column vector are not the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, for a symmetric matrix, the column space is identical to the row-space.  This follows fairly immediately from the respective definitions.

The matrix $P$ of eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix $A$ satisfies
$$
A = PDP^{-1} \implies AP = PD
$$
Where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of (real) eigenvalues.  It follows then that
$$
(AP)^T = P^T A^T = P^T A = \\
(PD)^T = D^T P^T = D P^T
$$
That is, $P^TA = D P^T$, so that $P^T$ is a matrix of left eigenvectors.